# Save Athena QueryExecutionID as a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I'm working with a Lambda in Python 3.8, and I'm trying to save an Athena Execution ID as a variable (just that large value) that was executed from a query by another Lambda.
Can anyone help me with some example?

Thanks!

This is the code what I'm using right now

```
import boto3
import botocore

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    
    jsonFile = client.list_query_executions (
        MaxResults=1,
        WorkGroup='primary')
    print(jsonFile)
```

And when I test it I'm obtaining this

```
Test Event Name
MyEvent

Response
null

Function Logs
START RequestId: 38974cd3-2a44-4069-8aa3-343cf1ac24e5 Version: $LATEST
{'QueryExecutionIds': ['9f8503fb-b687-459c-af26-95acfbaf0390'], 'NextToken': 'ATnkcz1IKKJdDAnAUytZPJTJT/9jH4k4EVZ4BF3/rg6beFeS+d2nYCOb8VLOkCrzTEawF9PRp5rEwfmVpg63R6MgD4RRFYgutSeWgA7MHpgbLufOWLYWYY7QvEo9WlULWZJlocDVoqE3qUrCuDV98tyhTl4RbwpI8oFgXb5aIo5+kRujW3z5UswqQSC5xVu/IYs0REtNpgosraoaEPbMnKKS1quE8gOo6YP+Lebx0Ab5hJMNf9kfh4rWrxK0C9ednH7nggKpEeCrX/8wxCFnf7JETNqXGO+CUYHpLKwrtjefF+fmSRVQqp+dm9Sf0BSrfcFW+i/iu4g/', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '012b62fd-9682-496d-a08a-0fafbcbc8705', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'date': 'Mon, 13 Dec 2021 12:27:43 GMT', 'x-amzn-requestid': '012b62fd-9682-496d-a08a-0fafbcbc8705', 'content-length': '409', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
END RequestId: 38974cd3-2a44-4069-8aa3-343cf1ac24e5
REPORT RequestId: 38974cd3-2a44-4069-8aa3-343cf1ac24e5  Duration: 444.32 ms Billed Duration: 445 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 67 MB  Init Duration: 466.57 ms

Request ID
38974cd3-2a44-4069-8aa3-343cf1ac24e5
```

I'm pretty interested in save the value of **QueryExecutionIds** (Just the numbers).

Of course I'm trying to print it first to make sure that I'm can capture it's value, then I will save it in a variable and use it properly.

Comment: Do you have any code that you tried to write yourself?

Comment: Do the two Lambdas run consecutively or are they completely independent? If one is a dependency of the other then you can coordinate them using Step Functions and you can pass the data around using the Payload property. On the other hand, if they run completely independently, you might need to store the value somewhere (DynamoDB maybe)?

Comment: I'v edited the post with more details. Thank you, guys